# Invariant subspaces, direct sum question

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a vector space V and a linear operator T from V to V. If V is direct sum of its subspaces U and W, and if U is T-invariant, can we claim that W is also T-invariant?

I tried proving this but I couldn't, and I am now not sure if this is true.

If it is not true, could you provide a counter example?

Comment: Consider $V=\mathbb{R}^2,U=\text{span}\{e_1\},W=\text{span}\{e_2\},$ and $T(x,y)=(x+y,y)$.

Comment: in general consider any non-zero nilpotent operator say where $\dim \ker T =1$.  If $U=\ker T$ how could $W$ be T-invariant since it is killed by $T^n$?  Nilpotent maps are a rich source of (counter)examples